# What's the Linux equivalent to Windows batch files?

Tags: android, compiling, batch

I have a batch file which I use to create an .apk file on my Windows machine.
Now I need to be able to create the .apk file in Ubuntu but I don't know how translate my .bat file to a script to be able to run it on Ubuntu.

Below is the batch file which works fine on Windows.  Will you please give me some hints on how I can run it on Ubuntu?

```
@echo off
set PAUSE_ERRORS=0
:user_configuration

:: Path to Flex SDK 
set FLEX_SDK=C:\sdk\flex_sdk_4.5.1.21328

:: Path to Android SDK
set ANDROID_SDK=C:\sdk\android

:validation
if not exist "%FLEX_SDK%\bin" goto flexsdk
if not exist "%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools" goto androidsdk
goto succeed

:validation
if not exist "%FLEX_SDK%\bin" goto flexsdk
if not exist "%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools" goto androidsdk
goto succeed

:flexsdk
echo.
echo ERROR: incorrect path to Flex SDK
echo.
if %PAUSE_ERRORS%==1 pause
exit

:androidsdk
echo.
echo ERROR: incorrect path to Android SDK in 'bat\SetupSDK.bat'
echo.

if %PAUSE_ERRORS%==1 pause
exit

:succeed
set PATH=%PATH%;%FLEX_SDK%\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools

:: Android packaging
set AND_CERT_NAME="PeymanApp"
set AND_CERT_PASS=fd
set AND_CERT_FILE=cert\SampleApp.p12
set AND_ICONS=icons/android

set AND_SIGNING_OPTIONS=-storetype pkcs12 -keystore "%AND_CERT_FILE%" -storepass     %AND_CERT_PASS%

:: Application descriptor
set APP_XML=application.xml

:: Files to package
set APP_DIR=bin
set FILE_OR_DIR=-C %APP_DIR% .

:: Your application ID (must match <id> of Application descriptor)
set APP_ID=air.com.doitflash.SampleApp

:: Output packages
set DIST_PATH=dist
set DIST_NAME=PeymanApp

:validation
%SystemRoot%\System32\find /C "<id>%APP_ID%</id>" "%APP_XML%" > NUL
if errorlevel 1 goto badid
goto end_validation

:badid
echo.
echo ERROR: Application ID (APP_ID) does NOT match Application descriptor '%APP_XML%'     (id)

echo.

:end_validation

set TARGET=
set PLATFORM=android

::call bat\Packager.bat
if "%PLATFORM%"=="android" goto android-config

:android-config
set CERT_FILE=%AND_CERT_FILE%
set SIGNING_OPTIONS=%AND_SIGNING_OPTIONS%
set ICONS=%AND_ICONS%
set DIST_EXT=apk
set TYPE=apk
goto start

:start
if not exist "%CERT_FILE%" goto certificate
:: Output file
set FILE_OR_DIR=%FILE_OR_DIR% -C "%ICONS%" .
if not exist "%DIST_PATH%" md "%DIST_PATH%"
set OUTPUT=%DIST_PATH%\%DIST_NAME%%TARGET%.%DIST_EXT%
:: Package

echo true
echo.
call adt -package -target %TYPE%%TARGET% %OPTIONS% %SIGNING_OPTIONS% "%OUTPUT%"     "%APP_XML%" %FILE_OR_DIR% -extdir lib/
echo.
if errorlevel 1 goto failed
goto end

:certificate
echo Certificate not found: %CERT_FILE%
echo.

if %PAUSE_ERRORS%==1 pause
exit

:failed
echo APK setup creation FAILED.

if %PAUSE_ERRORS%==1 pause
exit

:end
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to learn to write bash scripts. These are the Linux equivalent of windows batch files. The syntax isn't too difficult to get your head around. I suggest googling as there are many great freely accessible tutorials.

I suggest [BASH Programming - Introduction HOW-TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)

Note that you will need to change your windows-style paths to Linux style. E.g.

```
my_drive_letter:\my_folder\myfile
```

becomes

```
/media/my_drive_label/my_folder/my_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed [wine [image: Install wine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine), then do the following command in a terminal:

```
wine cmd
```

This will open up a Windows command prompt. Start your `.bat` from there.

Answer (score 3):

## Learn python

You might want to [learn python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213798/would-python-make-a-good-substitute-for-the-windows-command-line-batch-scripts).

It's [easy to learn](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) and more readable than some [other scripting language](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#FSTRANGEREF)... ;-)

Comment: Python is a venerable programming message, powerful, but simple and easy to understand at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with recoding but there is a document that explains how shell-scripting works and what commands you need to use. I guess it should be sifficient to rewrite your script:

http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php

Comment: This should have been left as a comment.